# Jasmine Testing with Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I've included jasmine in an angular project and I'm trying to hook up a spec file to a file that has my angular controllers (so I can do unit tests). The problem is that I'm not entirely sure how to wire this up.

This is what the folder hierarchy for my project looks like:

```
project_folder/index.html
project_folder/js/controllers.js
project_folder/lib/jasmine/jasmine-standalone-2.3.4/spec/challengeSpec.js
```

Currently I want the tests for the controllers.js file (with the Angular code) to be in the challengeSpec.js file. How can I bring in the modules from the controllers.js file and use them in my tests? This is what some of the code from each of the files looks like:

```
controllers.js file:

var siteControllers = angular.module('siteControllers', []);
    fibonacciControllers.controller('pageController', ['$scope','$http', function ($scope, $http) {
    ...
});

challengeSpec.js file:

describe('siteControllers', function() {
    beforeEach(module('siteControllers'));
});
```

I know in the challengeSpec.js file I need to bring in the modules from the controllers.js file, but I'm not sure how this can be done. I've been doing some research that suggests I use Karma, but I'm not quite sure how this fits into the equation here. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Your test spec seems to be on a good start, but you should not put the file in the place you did.
Using Karma is needed as it is the 'test runner'. For a completer story from a-z I'd try reading this 
https://www.airpair.com/angularjs/posts/unit-testing-angularjs

Comment: So there's no way to use Jasmine alone? What would the standalone Jasmine framework be for then, just for vanilla javascript and no framework?

Comment: right. Karma knows about AngularJs specifics like promises, which is why you use it.